# Reason for always false directive if in C

Tags: c

Here is what I found in an open source project's code:

```
#if 0
static int print_cb(UNUSED void *ctx, void *i)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%i\n", *(int*)i);
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Can you explain me what's the reason for this always false if?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly to comment a piece of code.

Comment: This is a deactivated code in certain platform. This code may be activated to do file I/O opertions in host. However in target hardware this may be deactivated as some targets wont support file I/O especially in case of low end micro controllers.

Comment: Please have a look at [what-exactly-does-an-if-0-endif-block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852913/what-exactly-does-an-if-0-endif-block-do/2853104#2853104)

Comment: Another good read to use this way of deactivating code is that the code would still be treated as code by tools like source code formatters, which might destroy the format if the code were commented out using `/**/` or `//`.

Comment: It is called conditional compilation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simply a way to use the preprocessor to comment out (prevent from compiling) a large block of code. It's pretty common.

It's better than using the actual comment syntax since it doesn't nest. If you have:

```
int foo = 13; /* This won't be needed. */
```

you can't comment it out by doing:

```
/*
int foo = 13; /* This won't be needed. */
*/
```

since the comment syntax doesn't nest, the above will not compile. Using the `#if 0` method goes around that limitation.

Comment: Very nice reason. Good logic :)

Comment: @artaxerxe Read [9.3 Conditional Compilation](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx9c.html) and [3.3.4 Conditional Compilation](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap3/subsection2.1.3.4.html)

Answer (score 7):

It is a way of commenting code out.  The condition will never be met (0 is never true) so the preprocessor will exclude the code from the compile.

It is typically used on bigger blocks of code that might have some embedded multi-line comments `/*  */` that cannot be commented out by enclosing them in another multi-line comment.

Answer (score 4):

That is just to disable this code section like Multiline comment. It is better method which avoids nested comments.

Answer (score 1):

From [preprocessor definition here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

> Preprocessor directives are lines included in the code of our programs that are not program statements but directives for the preprocessor. These lines are always preceded by a hash sign (#). The preprocessor is executed before the actual compilation of code begins, therefore the preprocessor digests all these directives before any code is generated by the statements.

So, `#if 0` will be decided as `#if (false)` (losely saying), that means, do not enter the block and skip. A way of commenting out something.