# Why would anyone want to use #if 0 && something?

Tags: c

I am taking a peak at the [GraphSketcher code](https://github.com/graphsketcher) (iOS and OSX) code and I saw this:

```
#if 0 && defined(DEBUG_bungi)
#endif
```

I might accept `#if 0` [as a way to comment code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852913/what-exactly-does-an-if-0-endif-block-do), but why do an AND if the condition will always be false?

An example of [that usage can be found here](https://github.com/graphsketcher/GraphSketcher/blob/master/GraphSketcher/Model/RSAxis.m#L26), although this is used all over the code.

Comment: So that you can add `#define 0 1` somewhere and ruin everyone's day.

Comment: You could link to the specific file in the repo to provide more context.

Comment: Was the first thing I looked at in the code

Comment: OK, I found it. You cleverly left out the fact that the bit between `#if` and `#endif` isn't empty. It's so you can quickly switch parts on, but only in specific debug builds.

Comment: @moldbnilo it is used a lot in the code, that is why I didn't want to focus on a specific file because it could influence answers. For the sake of the example I have added a file in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's still a way to temporarily comment code.**

If you want to use `#if 0` as a way to comment a block of code that happens to be a pre-existing `#if` block, this seems like a sensible way to do it. You don't lose the original `#if` logic to history, and simply remove the `0 &&` when you're done.

You could also write:

```
#if 0
#if defined(DEBUG_bungi)
#endif
#endif
```

but this is arguably more yucky.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to just disable de DEBUG_bungi? In this case I only find one situation where they do #ifdef DEBUG_bungi. The rest always has `#if 0 && defined(DEBUG_bungi)`

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: Maybe that macro is controlled by another, more all-encompassing macro, and they don't want to disable the entire thing, but _just_ this individual block of code? It's impossible to rationalise without knowing the specific codebase, but honestly I wouldn't waste too much time thinking about it.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida only the `0 &&` has to be added to uncomment something, and *no corresponding #endif* has to be added. it's quite clever, really

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the answer. Probably I am overthinking :)

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily comment code where there was already an `#if`? Once you want to reinstate the code, you remove the `0 &&` and keep the rest.

That being said, it is a bit ugly to commit something like this to version control.

Comment: Why remove it at all? Just modify one character to make it `if 1 && ...`

Comment: @Brandin: Because it's ugly? Unless you think you want to disable this piece of code _again_ in the future, in which case it is probably time for an extra #define symbol.

Comment: I agree. But remember the situation here is that its somebody elses code where this pattern is being used throughout. I don't think its that useful personally, but if you change that then while we're at it why don't we also go through every `if 0 &&` and give each one a special name. How about also renaming class/struct properties to camelCase or switch to using the One True Brace Style, etc.

Comment: Okay, I didn't look at the code in question. If this is a pattern, better to keep it for now.