# How to do block comment in fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have seen `/* block comment */` for block commenting in C++. I  know I can do line commenting by using `!` or `c`, but is there any option for block commenting in Fortran?

Answer (score 20):

No, the strange concept of block comments is alien to Fortran. Your editor or development environment might provide a way to comment a block of lines in one go.

Comment: For Emacs user this would be [fortran-comment-region](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fortran-Comments.html) (first mark the region; second use `C-c ;`)

Comment: For vim users this would be :'<,'>s/^/!/g which use a regex on the marked region (marked with v) to match the start of the row and insert a ! with flag g = globally which does it on every match of ^=start of row.

Answer (score 19):

You can do a little hack though:

```
go to 100
 ! CHUNK OF CODE YOU WANT TO COMMENT OUT
100 continue
```

Yeah, I know it's horrible but it works. :)

Comment: This is a hack I've used a bit, but it's worth noting that this (probably) requires the "commented-out" code to be compilable.

Answer (score 12):

If your FORTRAN compiler supports preprocessor macros then a popular method is to use ([What exactly does an #if 0 ..... #endif block do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852913/what-exactly-does-an-if-0-endif-block-do))

```
#if 0
...
Your comments ...
go here ...
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

A line with a c, C, *, d, D, or ! in column one is a comment line; except that if the -xld option is set, then the lines starting with D or d are compiled as debug lines. The d, D, and ! are nonstandard.

If you put an exclamation mark (!) in any column of the statement field, except within character literals, then everything after the ! on that line is a comment.

Comment: This is true only for a particular compiler. And only for fixed form sources.

Answer (score 3):

It is much simpler to use a text editor which allows for multiline commenting using "SHIFT + /"!

Answer (score -3):

Do the following:

- Go to the first line among all the multiple block lines to comment and place the typing position to the first column,
- Press Alt+Shift in the keyboard,
- Select all the lines to comment,
- Unpress Alt+Shift from the keyboard
- Type C/c
  It will work then . Check that out and tell me in the comments. Cheers!

Comment: This does not do anything at all in my text editor.

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to mention that I am using the above in the sublime text editor with fortran packages installed too .

Comment: it does not work.

Answer (score -5):

In [Sublime text editor](https://www.sublimetext.com/) it can be used *Toggle Comment* (Ctrl+7) or *Toggle Block Comment*.

Comment: This is a blatantly unrelated answer.

Comment: What is Mayús? This should be a comment, really, the question asks how a block comment looks like in the source file, not which key shortcut an editor uses. Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049963/how-to-do-block-comment-in-fortran/44620660#comment33570578_22050130 - a comment, not answer. Wait until you gain priviliges for commenting.

Comment: It's the way that I comment a fortran 90 code. Is one of the ways to do it.

Comment: If you do not know what is (Mayús) (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Accesos_directos_en_el_teclado), you can ignore.