# Can we indeed avoid goto in all cases?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, goto

Fortran 90 and later strongly recommend not to use `goto` statement.

However, I still feel forced to use it in either of the two cases:

**Case 1** -- Instruct to re-enter the input value, e.g.

```
      program reenter   
10    print*,'Enter a positive number'
      read*, n

      if (n < 0) then
      print*,'The number is negative!'
      goto 10
      end if

      print*,'Root of the given number',sqrt(float(n))

      stop
      end program reenter
```

**Case 2** -- To comment a large continuous part of a program (an equivalent to `/* ... */` in C). 
    Eg.

```
       print*,'This is to printed'
       goto 50
       print*,'Blah'
       print*,'Blah Blah'
       print*,'Blah Blah Blah'   
 50    continue
       print*,'Blahs not printed'
```

How can I get rid of using `goto` statement and use some alternatives in the above two cases in Fortran 90?

Comment: To answer the title question from the theoretical standpoint: [Böhm-Jacopini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem)

Answer (score 4):

Case 1

What you have is an indefinite loop, looping until a condition is met.

```
do
  read *, n
  if (n.ge.0) exit
  print *, 'The number is negative!'
end do
! Here n is not negative.
```

Or one could use a `do while` lump.

---

Case 2

A non-Fortran answer is: [use your editor/IDE's block comment tool to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22050130/3157076).

In Fortran, such flow control can be

```
if (i_dont_want_to_skip) then
  ! Lots of printing
end if
```

or (which isn't Fortran 90)

```
printing_block: block
  if (i_do_want_to_skip) exit printing_block
  ! Lots of printing
end block printing_block
```

---

But that isn't to say that all `goto`s should be avoided, even when many/all can be.

Comment: Another possibility for case 2 would be to use preprocessor directives.

Comment: Indeed, good point.  Although I'd put it as a non-Fortran way it would be very much like the `if` construct.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you mean by "continuous part of a program" case 2 could be jumping *out* of some block structure, eg:

```
             do i = 1,n
                  ...
                  goto 1
                  ...
             enddo
              ...

        1      continue
```

If you encounter such thing it can be quite a challenge to unravel the code logic and replace with modern structured coding.  All the more reason not to "comment" that way..

Comment: Thanks all for the discussion. @PetrH, could you elaborate what you meant by "preprocessor directives"?