# Error return, gotos and code duplication in modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, goto

In legacy Fortran code it's relative common to find this kind construct:

```
irc=0
...
if (foo) goto 10
...
if (bar) goto 10
...
return
10 irc=1
return
```

i.e., the `irc` variable holds the return code, and whenever an error occurs, a simple `goto 10` accomplishes both setting a value and returning from the subroutine.

In modern code, where one tries to avoid `goto`s at all cost (https://xkcd.com/292/), what would be the best way to rewrite this? The trivial inlining causes a lot of code duplication and alternate `return`s (which look almost as bad as `goto`s):

```
irc=0
...
if (foo) then
  irc=1
  return
end if
...
if (bar) then
  irc=1
  return
end if
...
return
```

To avoid code duplication one could use an internal subroutine (especially if there are several statements to repeat every time), but that still leaves the `return`s. Or is there some way to force a return on the host subroutine from the internal one? Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a procedure to complete execution of a distinct procedure (except through program termination). That is, an internal procedure's RETURN statement can't be used to manage the desired flow.

However, the desired flow here can be managed with a [BLOCK construct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476018/3157076) such as in the following way:

```
main_flow: block
   irc=0
   ...
   if (foo) exit main_flow
   ...
   if (bar) exit main_flow
   ...
   return
end block main_flow
...
```

Clearly the conditions and actions can be more involved, and there can be a test outside the block if one is averse to returning from middles of procedures.

The block construct is such that an EXIT from within acts like a GO TO to the end of the block.

DO constructs with a single iteration count can also [act in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553892/3157076).