# Compilation error about gcc preprocessing directives

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

There is the following code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#if 0

第一步：加载地球，可异步执行
    9 、 扩展链接子视图

#endif

int main() {
    double v;
    sscanf(".1", "%lf", &v);
    printf("%f", v);
}
```

Both `clang` and `msvc` compile normally, only `gcc` reports an error:

```bash
...
<Compilation failed>

# For more information see the output window
x86-64 gcc 12.2 - 587ms
<source>:6:7: error: extended character 、 is not valid in an identifier
    6 |     9 、 扩展链接子视图
      |       ^
```

Some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2852913/13792395) mention that `#if 0` is identical to commenting out the block.
Is this a `gcc` error or misuse of the #if instruction?
[online version](https://godbolt.org/z/7f8KcqWjx)

Comment: fyi the `¬` on a UK keyboard also reproduces the problem - live - https://godbolt.org/z/oaPn559nq

Comment: It also throws a warning on unterminated string literals, but regular ASCII identifiers can be there without any issue: https://godbolt.org/z/G4jM9vTvx

Comment: I think no matter `#if 0`, everything in the whole file has to be an identifier.

Comment: @KamilCuk In the pre-processor - _"...Otherwise, if the specified condition evaluates false, the controlled code block is skipped..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional

Comment: @KamilCuk The C++ draft Standard just says _"...skipped..."_ [\[cpp.cond #14\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.cond#14), it might be a C vs C++ difference.

Comment: I think KamilCuk might be right, the code should consist of preprocessing tokens even within `#if 0`. Although standard explicitly mentions "each non-whitespace character that cannot be one of the above" as a [preprocessing token](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#nt:preprocessing-token), which should allow weird UTF-8 characters as well.

Comment: I started to write an answer, but the more I read, the less I understand. Mismatched `"` or `'` as preprocessing token is strictly named as UB in [`[5.4.2]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#2), but does that apply to skipped tokens per [`[15.2.14]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.cond#14)? What about [`[lex.charset]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset), which doesn't seem to be touched by [P2295R6](https://wg21.link/P2295R6)?

Comment: It think the error stems from [this part](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libcpp/charset.cc#L1839) in the gcc source.