# What is this C idiom (if (1))?

Tags: c, openssl, idioms, conditional-compilation

I noticed a strange idiom in openssl source code, [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/165f1c3ef39680471339d21b9f6c12ea86b4a26a/apps/passwd.c#L242-L260) and repeated below:

```
if ((in == NULL) && (passwds == NULL)) {
        if (1) {                                    (* <---- HERE *)
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_UI
            /* build a null-terminated list */
            static char *passwds_static[2] = { NULL, NULL };

            passwds = passwds_static;
            if (in == NULL)
                if (EVP_read_pw_string
                    (passwd_malloc, passwd_malloc_size, "Password: ",
                     !(passed_salt || in_noverify)) != 0)
                    goto end;
            passwds[0] = passwd_malloc;
        } else {
#endif
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "password required\n");
            goto end;
        }
}
```

It seems that this piece of code is equivalent to:

```
if ((in == NULL) && (passwds == NULL)) {
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_UI
        /* build a null-terminated list */
        static char *passwds_static[2] = { NULL, NULL };

        passwds = passwds_static;
        if (in == NULL)
            if (EVP_read_pw_string
                (passwd_malloc, passwd_malloc_size, "Password: ",
                 !(passed_salt || in_noverify)) != 0)
                goto end;
        passwds[0] = passwd_malloc;
#else
        BIO_printf(bio_err, "password required\n");
        goto end;
#endif
}
```

I ruled out some explanations:

- it could be to introduce block scope for `passwds_static`, but the enclosing `if` would serve a similar purpose
- it could be a construct that through several meaningful transformations becomes meaningless, but that construct is there [since the introduction of `OPENSSL_NO_UI`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/923b1857decf4440b13b82f2aa7cf1189327d1a3#diff-16eb4f58bda236c67d287baad522e84d).

Am I missing something here? What are the advantages of this `if (1)`? Is this used in other code bases?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that the sole purpose of it is to avoid and `#else` clause for whatever reason

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266060/why-would-somebody-use-an-if-1-c-preprocessor-directive?

Comment: @CristiFati - No. This isn't about `#if 1`, since that construct doesn't appear at all in the question. It's about `if(1)`.

Comment: Indeed, it's not about either `#if 0`, `#if 1`, or `if (0)`.

Comment: The only discernible difference is that using the prerprocessor alone won't produce a warning about unreachable code. But I highly doubt that was the intent.

Comment: On the warning side, this codes compiles cleanly, except that when `OPENSSL_NO_UI` is not defined, `in_noverify` is reported as not used. That happens both in the `if (1)` and `#else` cases so it does not seem to be the reason.

Comment: Perhaps the intention is relevant to unit test purposes. First solution (with `if(1)`) gives a way to test the entire function which several branches. However, the second solution might require configuration changes to the test engine which in many cases is complicated. Just to summarize my point of view, the approach is good to focus unit testing on code level, but not on configuration level.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah, yes, I missed the _#_ (and the indent). But I imagine it might serve the same purpose, or considering  that in older _OpenSSL_ versions (including 1.1.0-pre*) only what's inside `if (1) {..}` is present, maybe they will want to change the default behavior in the future (wo needing to recompile w/wo `OPENSSL_NO_UI`).

Comment: @JeremyP, ahahaha, looking to the coding style I assume you are right ))

Comment: @dmi The comment is intended to be light hearted but it does have an element of truth. OpenSSL is  partly responsible for some of the worst bugs to affect Linux security and a lot of its problems can be blamed on the appalling unmaintainable code base. See [this article](https://www.openbsd.org/papers/eurobsdcon2014-libressl.html) to get a flavour of the problems.

Comment: Judging from numerous SO questions about all kinds of oddities in the OpenSSL source, it does appear to be a big pile of crap indeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking at other similar places, [I found an explanation](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a4c74e88e4bfce51cca22ed9d73d7d6bd96b4b87/crypto/bio/bss_acpt.c#L186-L196):

```
if (1) { /* This is a trick we use to avoid bit rot.
          * at least the "else" part will always be
          * compiled.
          */
#ifdef AF_INET6
    family = AF_INET6;
} else {
#endif
    BIOerr(BIO_F_ACPT_STATE, BIO_R_UNAVAILABLE_IP_FAMILY);
    goto exit_loop;
}
```

In most cases (including their CI I guess), `OPENSSL_NO_UI` is not defined, so *both* branches are compiled. If the API one of the branches uses changes, it will be spotted by the compiler, and it can be fixed, without having to test all the compile-time switches.

Answer (score 2):

It is apparently used to remove code that shouldn't be executed, similar to using `#ifdef` compiler switches. Most often strange things like this is an indication of poor version control more than anything else.

Please note that this is not recommended practice - there should be no source code present that never gets executed in no circumstances. It is better practice to use version control, or if that's not possible use compiler switches, or if that's not possible then "comment out" the code.

Answer (score 0):

the statement:

```
if(1) {
```

is to always have a matching opening brace for the closing brace.